# How can I withdraw my mbtc on my testnet 3 wallet?

Tags: transactions, testnet

Pls can you help me on how to exchange my mBtc on my testnet 3 wallet to my local currency and withdraw it? Pls tell me if this is possible..? I was paid to my testnet wallet and I  want to withdraw it.

Pls help

Answer (score 2):

Testnet coins have no value - there is no way to transfer them to any exchange or broker and exchange for fiat.

If someone is paying you on a testnet and claiming it is valid reimbursement or payment for anything, they are scamming you.